# Can we filter the display of a spreadsheet according to the user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet viewable by multiple users.
Some boxes are filled by them, and I wish that if the user "A" filled a box, the user "B" does not see the value entered.
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].